# Accessing class variables in a mutable array of objects in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

In objective-c, how can I access individual class properties in a mutable array of objects?

I created a class 'Person' with properties NSString 'firstName' and NSString 'Lastname'. I then created a mutable array of 'Persons' with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray * personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[personArray addObject: firstPerson];
[personArray addObject: secondPerson];
[personArray addObject: thirdPerson];
```

How can I can access the 'firstName' property for the 'secondPerson'?

I know the C++ equivalent would be something like:

```
personArray[1].firstName
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try `[array objectAtIndex:1]` to access single element in array?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to import the `Person` header file where you want to use the public header information (I'm assuming the property is public).

```
#import "Person.h"
```

and then you use the object on the array casting it to the right class

```
((Person *)(personArray[1])).firstName;
```

This is needed because the object returned with `personArray[1]` is of type `id`, therefore the compiler doesn't have clue about the object type. Casting it to the right class makes the compiler happy (you are informing it about the type of the object in the array), allowing you to use its public property.

An alternative could be to use

```
[personArray[1] firstName]
```

It works because using this notation you can call on an `id` object whatever method\property of the interfaces seen by the compiler. In this case the compiler trusts you, if you use a property\method that doesn't belong to the class of that object, you'll have a crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You need change "class variables" to "property" then access the property the same as you do in C++

```
personArray[1].firstName
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that these aren't variables, they are properties -- I edited my post to reflect this. I tried doing it the same way as in C++ but Xcode tells me that the "property 'firstName' not found on object type id"